# Laravel validator with a wildcard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i want to make a laravel validator that validates the the fields inside an un-named array ( 0,1,2,3 ) that is inside an array

so my array is like

```
array [ //the form data
  "items" => array:2 [ //the main array i want to validate
    0 => array:2 [ // the inner array that i want to validate its data
      "id" => "1"
      "quantity" => "1000"
     ]
    1 => array:2 [
     "id" => "1"
     "quantity" => "1000"
     ]
  // other fields of the form,
  ]

]
```

so what i want is something like

```
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'items.*.id' => 'required' //notice the star *
  ]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Laravel 5.2**

The syntax in the question is now supported

http://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#validating-arrays

**Laravel 5.1**

First create the validator with all of your other rules. Use the `array` rule for items

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'items' => 'array',
    // your other rules here
]);
```

Then use the Validator `each` method to apply a set of rules to every item in the items array.

```
$validator->each('items', [
    'id'       => 'required',
    'quantity' => 'min:0', 
]);
```

This will automatically set these rules for you...

```
items.*.id       => required
items.*.quantity => min:0
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L261

Comment: Great! Did not know about that. Should definitely be included in the docs!

Comment: looks like the new laravel ( 5.2 ) added my suggestion :D

Comment: @AlhasanIQ yep and it is nice to be able to set all the rules in one place. I'll update my answer

Comment: Any idea how to specify custom messages for those items.*.* rules?

Comment: @James it should be the same as regular messages: `'items.*.id.required' => 'Item ID is required'`. I don't believe there is any way (built in) to reference the `*` key in the message, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do something like that:

```
    $rules = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $rules["items.$i.id"] = "required";
    }
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
```

Comment: This works, but Laravel already has an `each` method which accomplishes the same thing, so why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Sure? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#available-validation-rules  I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: not everything is documented. It's in the source, see the link in my answer