# Laravel validation of input field with wildcard

Tags: wildcard, user-input, laravel-validation

I have a form that dynamically generates input fields, for instance:

```
input['Supplier1],
input['Supplier2'],
input['Supplier3'],
```

and so on. The user can create anywhere between 1 and 10 of these input fields.

I am using Laravel's built-in validation feature, and was wondering if there's a way to validate a field with a wildcard.

In other words, instead of creating separate rules for 'Supplier1', 'Supplier2', etc., is it possible to write something along the lines of 'Supplier^' where the '^' symbol represents any given character.

The rules are currently:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'Description1' => 'required|min:2',
        'Supplier1' => 'canBeEmpty|exists:suppliers,SupplierName'
    ];
}
```

'canBeEmpty' is a custom rule that allows the field to be submitted empty.

Comment: [Laravel validator with a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33368759/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the 'supplier' inputs as part of an Array, you could utilize a solution like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33371994/613703:

Construct your inputs in the following way:

```
<input type='text' name='suppliers[]' value='theValue' />
<input type='text' name='suppliers[]' value='theValue' />
etc...


$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'suppliers' => 'array',
    // your other rules here
]);

// Here you can set the rules for each Supplier in your Array
$validator->each('suppliers', [
    'id'       => 'required',
    'quantity' => 'min:0', 
]);
```