# Laravel array field validation

Tags: arrays, validation, laravel-5.1

How can I validate an array value in Laravel 5.1? Each values of the array should be validated. Number of array values may increase or decrease. But the name will be same. My sample input will be like,

```
emails[] = 'mail0@example.com',
emails[] = 'mail1@example.com',
```

I gave the validation rule like,

```
'emails' => 'required|email'
```

But when I give more than one values, it returns email invalid error because the email input is array. How can I validate this? Should I write custom rule?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33371994/3845839) I have tried something like,

```
$validator->each('emails', 'required|email')
```

But not working.

Comment: This questions is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368759/laravel-validator-with-a-wildcard/33371807#33371807

Comment: My input array format is different. I do not have any sub arrays. So I have tried like, `$validator->each('emails', 'required|email')`. Still not working.

Comment: you have missed the point for declaring 'emails' => 'array' in your rules.. I will show you an example in an answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to validate an array value.
  You can use in the validation place like below,

```
    'email.*' => 'required|email'
```

If it is an object like,

```
    {
      'email' : [
                  {
                    'email' : 'x@google.com'
                  },
                  {
                    'email' : 'y@google.com'
                  }
                 ]
    }
```

Then you need to use like below,

```
   'email.*.email' => 'required|email'
```

Thse are the best way of validate an array elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example of what your are looking for ( hopefully )

This is a simple blade file that just shows a form with two email fieds and a short error display:

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <p>{{ $error }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endif

<form action="{{ route('emails.store') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input name='emails[]'>
    <input name="emails[]">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Inside the store method of my controller I put:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'emails' => 'array',
        // your other rules here
    ]);

    $validator->each('emails', 'required|email');

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
    }

    dd('success');
}
```

This is working as expected and validates all emails[] fields

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this from the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: I have tried that already by giving '*.emails' => 'required|email'. But no validation. But I think it is for laravel 5.2. I have Laravel 5.1