# laravel validate array fields

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to validate array field using laravel validate functionality as follow

```
$this->validate($request,['prodActualQty' => 'required|numeric','actQty[]' => 'required'
],$messages);
```

my input file is: `<input class='form-control' type='text' name='actQty[]'>`

It gives error if fields are blank but it still gives error even we fill the fields.

Comment: Just remove [] `'actQty' => 'required'`

Comment: then it doesn't produce any error it means form gets submitted.

Comment: What message do you get when you try to submit and there's a value in the required fields?

Comment: [Laravel validator with a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33371994/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2 you can validate Form array elements using wildcards keyword.

So as per your situation you can either remove [] like below

```
$this->validate($request->all(), [
    'prodActualQty'     => 'required',
    'actQty'            => 'required'
]);
```

Or use wildcard operator

```
$this->validate($request->all(), [
    'prodActualQty'     => 'required',
    'actQty.*'          => 'required'
]);
```

Comment: thanks... i just get it.. but when write message for error it gives all numbers of error equals to input fields. `$messages = ['actQty.*.required' => 'Please enter  rawmaterial actual quantity'];`

Comment: For custom message you need to write another argument in validate method. like this
$this->validate($request->all(), [
    'prodActualQty'     => 'required',
    'actQty.*'          => 'required'
], [
    'actQty.1'         =>  'some validation message for actQty.1',
    'actQty.2'         =>  'some validation message for actQty.2',
]);

Comment: yeap.. but i dont know about number of array fields are there... so writing actQty.1, actQty.2 will give problems again.