# Laravel - validating an array

Tags: forms, validation, laravel-5

I have a comma separated list what I am trying to put in my table.

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $request->groups);
           $groups = explode(',', $string);
           $data = [];
            foreach ($groups as $group) {
                $data[] = [
                    'campaign_id' => 'xxxxxxx',
                    'group_name' => $group,
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now()
                ];
            }
    DB::table('groups')->insert($data);
```

This work fine, however there is no validation. What is the best way to validate this list? Can I use the laravel validator.

Comment: [Laravel validator with a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33371994/6521116)