# Laravel Validate Array of Inputs

Tags: arrays, forms, laravel, validation

I have a form:

```php
<input type="text" name="name[1]">
<input type="text" name="name[2]">
<input type="text" name="name[3]">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I've created form validation file with rules:

```php
class formRequest extends FormRequest {
....
public function rules()
{
    return ['name.*' => 'unique:names'];
}

public function messages()
{
    return ['name.unique' => 'Name is already in DB!'];
}
```

After submitting the form with value (e.g. 'John') in input (e.g. `name[1]`), which already exists in the DB, I get:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name.1' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `names` where `name`.`1` = John)

So it's treating `name.*` as for creating another field name, instead of looping through the array.

My Laravel Framework is version 5.4.19. According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#validating-arrays), the `name.*` should work to iterate through an array during validation.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Laravel validator with a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33368759/6521116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default if you didn't provide a column name for the `unique` rule, Laravel will add the input name, and in your case the input name is a number.

to fix this issue change the rule to the following instead:

```
return ['name.*' => 'unique:names,name'];
```

Comment: Hey, man! I've spent a day looking for this solution. Where did they write it that I should provide column name???:) This really makes learning programming so hard, because you just don't know where to look for the needed information and spend days trying this and that...

Comment: Do you have an advice on how to learn programming, or, particularly, Laravel?:)

Comment: Actually the documentation of Laravel is good when you faced a problem i suggest to start from there, and the best website to learn Laravel is Laracast but it is not free :( check unique validation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: thank you! I've read that page several times before posting this question,  but didn't get to the end where they list 'Availbale Validation Rules"... Next time I'll read whole page:)